# What Cable do I need to connect Bose L1S and Reloop Beatpad 2

Tags: cable, connector

My controller Reloop Beatpad2 has two balanced XLR outputs, whilst the Bose L1S has one analogue input for line-level analogue input via 0.63 cm TRS phone cable. 
(as seen in picture).

[image]

I am confused as to which exact cable I need to connect them to have full stereo sound. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run balanced. You can use the RCA master outputs. But to have actual stereo you need 2 speakers. You can't get stereo out of a single speaker.